# WPF win app and browser app

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm hearing this alot, that you can develop an app in WPF and run it as a desktop app or in a browser.

Is this really true?

I've install visual studio 2010 and I see 2 project templates : WPF Windows Application and WPF Browser Application (XBAP).

Currently reading a book on WPF, it talks about Page-Base app, which can be use for navigation. To creatre an app to run on your browser you have to use the WPF Browser Application.

So if I start with WPF Windows Application template can I run it in a browser ? I am assuming not since most of my class will be Window and not Page ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct; you can't.  (Although you might want to look into ClickOnce)

You are hearing that you can use the same *code* in a WPF client application and a browser (Using XBAP or Silverlight).  However, you do need to make separate projects (which can reference a common library).  (Although you might want to look into Silverlight 3 desktop apps)

Comment: So better starts with Silverlight rather than WPF ... 
What are the limitation of this ? Is it possible to create pop-up screen ( I guess not since it's like a web-app ... )

Comment: For a silverlight app, can you still access the local machine directories or ressources for example ? it's not really like a web-app where it's hosted on a server ... so I'm assuming yes?